# W3 Totla catche error?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, w3-total-cache

I have w3 total cache error message. I delete file from wp-content  (advanced-catch.php,db.php,w3tc-config.php) and then delete w3 plugin . And again re-install this plugin ,.

But i have same error message.

```
W3 Total Cache Error: Files and directories could not be automatically created to complete the installation.
```

Please execute commands manually
or use FTP form to allow W3 Total Cache make it automatically

Any help.. ?

Thannks

Answer (score 0):

The plugin needs access to your .htaccess file in order to write its changes. Make sure your file permissions allow this. Also, check out -

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/w3-total-cache-error-files-and-directories-could-not-be-automatically-created-t

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/w3-total-cache-error-files-and-directories-could-not-be-automatically-created-1

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your attention. Yes, i checked this all.  But finally , i solve this . It was because of i added www before it was only http : //mywebsite.com

now its working .. Thanks